# Oraclize failing to return data when using example contract

Tags: solidity, oracles, external-api

I am trying to use the example Oraclize contracts at https://github.com/oraclize/ethereum-examples/tree/master/solidity, including `KrakenPriceTicker.sol`. Here's my contract (modified very slightly):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
import "github.com/oraclize/ethereum-api/oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol";

contract KrakenPriceTicker is usingOraclize {

    string public ETHXBT;
    uint public timesCalled;
    uint public timesFailed;

    event newOraclizeQuery(string description);
    event newKrakenPriceTicker(string price);


    function KrakenPriceTicker() payable {
        oraclize_setProof(proofType_TLSNotary | proofStorage_IPFS);
    }

    function __callback(bytes32 myid, string result, bytes proof) {
        ETHXBT = result;
        newKrakenPriceTicker(ETHXBT);
        update();
    }

    function update() payable {
        if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > this.balance) {
            newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee");
            timesFailed++;
        } else {
            newOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer..");
            oraclize_query(60, "URL", "json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c.0");
            timesCalled++;
        }
    }

}
```

When the `update()` function is called and some ether and gas sent with it, it should call the kraken.com api and update the value of `ETHXBT` with what's returned. However, the value of `ETHXBT` is always blank. I know the `oraclize_query` is being called because the `timesCalled` variable does increment. So there appears to be an issue with the result returned, though going directly to https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT shows there shouldn't be any problem.

I've deployed the above contract at https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2c51daecf702f2afe3abee2cc84570ee17f75650 (I've tried to call `update()` several times).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query is working on the Oraclize Test site. You can see it working [here](http://app.oraclize.it/home/test_query#VVJMKEdFVCk=:anNvbihodHRwczovL2FwaS5rcmFrZW4uY29tLzAvcHVibGljL1RpY2tlcj9wYWlyPUVUSFhCVCkucmVzdWx0LlhFVEhYWEJULmNbMF0=). It has a request like:

```
json(https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Ticker?pair=ETHXBT).result.XETHXXBT.c[0]
```

with a response of `0.068000`

It seems your syntax is incorrect when you use `.result.XETHXXBT.c.0` instead of `.result.XETHXXBT.c[0]` since the result is an array and not a key named `0`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the ropsten test network I was using was having issues. I believe the code I posted should normally run fine.